# Python Password Generatr with read and random module

Tags: python, random, read-write

im kinda new to python and am programming a password generator. As of now, i think i am at a plateau where i need explanation.
At the end, where i want to generate a password with the user input given above, i get a type error
(TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given)
What am I missing, so that the random.choice function is not working

```
import random



Uppercaseletters = open("Upper.txt").read()
Lowercaseletters = open("Lower.txt").read()
Numbers = open("Zahlen.txt").read()
Symbols = open("Symbole.txt").read()


Upperbool = True
Lowerbool = True
Numbersbool = True
Symbolsbool = True

whole = ""

if Upperbool:
    whole += Uppercaseletters

if Lowerbool:
    whole += Lowercaseletters

if Numbersbool:
    whole += Numbers

if Symbolsbool:
    whole += Symbols

print("Hello and welcome to the simple password generator.")


a = 1
b = 1

if b <= 10:
    amount = int(input("How many passwords do you want to generate? "))
else:
    print("You are exceeding the limit of a maximum of 10 Passwords")
    
# length auswählen lassen (maximal 20 Zeichen lang (Fehler prevention))
if a <= 20:     
    length = int(input("How long do you want your password to be? "))
else:
    print("That password will be too long, try a number below 20")

for x in range(amount):
    password = "".join(random.choice(whole, length))
    print(password)
```

Comment: `random.choice` returns only one element. If you need a sequence, call it repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like this:

```py
import random


Uppercaseletters = open("Upper.txt").read()
Lowercaseletters = open("Lower.txt").read()
Numbers = open("Zahlen.txt").read()
Symbols = open("Symbole.txt").read()

Upperbool = True
Lowerbool = True
Numbersbool = True
Symbolsbool = True

whole = ""

if Upperbool:
    whole += Uppercaseletters

if Lowerbool:
    whole += Lowercaseletters

if Numbersbool:
    whole += Numbers

if Symbolsbool:
    whole += Symbols

print("Hello and welcome to the BMD's simple password generator.")


amount = 100
length = 100

while amount>10:
    amount = int(input("How many passwords do you want to generate? "))
    if amount>10:
        print("You are exceeding the limit of a maximum of 10 Passwords")

while length>20:
    length = int(input("How long do you want your password to be? "))
    if length>20:
        print("That password will be too long, try a number below 20")


for passwords in range(amount):
    password = ""
    for character in range(length):
        password = password + random.choice(list(whole))
    print(password)
```

I modified it so that it does not allow amounts above 10 and lengths above 20.